# How to remove this in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to remove this [arrow thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4oF7.png) in MS Word

[image: arrow thing]

I tried everything like searching about this on the net but to my dismay, I found nothing. Please help.

Comment: what is it for? ... why do you want to remove it?

Comment: Too little detail to be possible to analyze and answer: Show WHERE in Word you see it.

Comment: You cannot remove this; you can change the style, though. See the posts supplied as answers. It is to help in reading and editing the document. It does not print. ---- 
@jsotola  - this is feature of Word since Word 2013

Comment: @CharlesKenyon thanks ... it is unclear if the OP actually knows what it is used for

Comment: that tiny thing doesn't have much meaning. Why didn't you take a larger screenshot for more context?

Answer (score 8):

That "arrow" appears because the style for that text is set to either Heading 1, Heading 2, etc. Clicking the arrow allows you to expand or collapse texts under that heading. To remove it, you must change the style to Normal or another style that is not for headings.

[image: Collapse/Expand text & Change styles]

Comment: THIS is useful answer. Although I am disappointed to hear that it is non-configurable for heading styles. Shame on you, Microsoft....

Answer (score 1):

"Expand/Collapse is a feature built-in to all the default heading styles in Word except for No Space and Normal. There is no option to disable the Expand/Collapse feature unless you will be using the Normal style or you will be creating a custom style based on the Normal formatting."

[How do you remove all instances of expand/collapse in Word 2016?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/how-do-you-remove-all-instances-of-expandcollapse/57fb3f29-3c02-48a2-aa3c-99fc2e0e5457#:%7E:text=Expand%2FCollapse%20is%20a%20feature,based%20on%20the%20Normal%20formatting.)

Comment: To Google, you need to know the jargon of Expand/Collapse.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon True, but even if you put into Google "remove arrow thing ms word" it comes up with a thread of people discussing it and talking about how you cannot remove it. [Removing the arrows that expand and collapse the headings in MS Word 2016](https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/33415852-removing-the-arrows-that-expand-and-collapse-the-h)

Answer (score 0):

When you’re working on a long, complicated document, you can collapse everything except the part you want to focus on. The ability to collapse and expand content in your document is based on its outline level. You can quickly add an outline level and make part of your document collapsible by adding a heading using Word's built-in styles.

Expand/Collapse is a feature built-in to all the default heading (outline level) styles in Word beginning with Word 2013. There is no option to disable the Expand/Collapse feature unless you will be using the Normal style or you will be creating a custom style based on the Normal formatting. You can use this [**article**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) as a reference on how to create a new style based on document formatting.

Answer (score 0):

These are collapsible styles, you will not be able to remove that arrow, unless you switch the style to normal.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is most likely due to the OP using one of the Heading styles.

However, it can still happen that you will have the expand/collapse arrows when using the Normal style. This is a problem I ran into from time to time for years, and no amount of Googling ever provided me with a solution, but I finally figured it out.

If the text is in the Normal style, and you still have expand/collapse arrows, what you need to do is click on the line(s) where you see the arrows, open the paragraph settings, and on the Indents and Spacing tab find where it says Outline Level. It will probably be set to 'Level 1'. If you change it to 'Body Text', the arrows will disappear, and you will no longer have to worry about accidentally collapsing random sections of the text.

If you're using one of the Heading styles, this option will be locked at Level 1.

I hope that helps someone. I know it drove me crazy for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the text in question.

Navigate to References --> click "Add Text" drop down

Select do not show on table of Contents.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was plagued by this, especially as if you printed a doc out, having accidentally collapsed a para, it didn't print the collapsed part.
I have solved it, however, by selecting all the text, right clicking (or going to the paragraph settings) and under the "general" settings, selecting "outline level". That seems to remove the little arrows, and the collapse function for the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove an instance of the expand/collapse feature: Select all >> right click >> styles >> clear formatting.